# How do I convert from this weird Coordinate unit to LngLat for use in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have a database full of rows if coordinate pairs like this:

ux: 6643641
uy: 264274
uz: NULL

I have been tasked to make all these coordinates appear on google maps as points of interest, but nobody could tell me what the hell those coordinates were.

What I need for Google Maps is longitude and lengtitude coordinates. I know the one can be converted to the other, but nothing more.

I realize this might not be the correct place to ask about coordinate systems, but I honestly couldn't think of any other place to state the question.

Thanks for any help!

---

That's my bad, I now see that there is more data for each row:

CoordSystemNumber: 23
CoordSystemName: EUREF89 UTM Sone 33

Comment: What country are these coordinates in?

Comment: There are hundreds of coordinate systems in the world. Just by looking at those it might be a little complicated.

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP. Other than that, this link might or not help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system However, unless you have a Rosetta stone of some sort (i.e. you could say that the above coordinates correspond to Nowhereville, Examplia), you might not be able to figure anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that format is called UTM. You need to know the Zone and Hemisphere to complete the conversion. Is there other data associated with this?

Comment: If "sone" is a number from 1-60, than it might be referring to Zone, which is require for converting UTM to Lat/Long. I could be way off.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this seems helpful :

```
x =   882880 meters
y = -4924482 meters
z =  3944130 meters

Geocentric latitude and longitude are not commonly used, but they are defined by
    latitude  = arctan( z / sqrt( x^2 + y^2 ) )
    longitude = arctan( y / x )
```

Taken from here :
http://www.cv.nrao.edu/~rfisher/Ephemerides/earth_rot.html

see this too :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

Answer (score 1):

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) might offer some help.

> The coordinates are often chosen such that one of the numbers represent vertical position, and two or three of the numbers represent horizontal position. A common choice of coordinates is latitude, longitude and elevation.